# Do turkey and chicken pastrami count as "processed meats" in terms of cancer risk (in light of the recent WHO publication)?

Tags: cancer

The World Health Organization (WHO) [recently concluded](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/health-34615621) that processed meats (including salami, pastrami, and hamburgers) cause cancer.

Instead, it is recommended to consume poultry, fish and beans as alternatives. What I don't understand is where poultry pastrami falls in this context - is it "processed" (and hence cancerous) or is it "poultry" (and hence safe)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the species of animal that matters; it's how the meat was prepared. 
According to the [Washington Post](http://www.washingtonpost.com/news/wonkblog/wp/2015/10/26/hot-dogs-bacon-and-other-processed-meats-cause-cancer-world-health-organization-declares/), WHO defines processed meats as:

> Processed meat includes hot dogs, ham, sausages, corned beef and beef
>   jerky — or any other meat that has been cured, **smoked**, **salted** or
>   otherwise changed to enhance flavor or improve preservation.

And according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastrami), pastrami is:

> Pastrami (Turkish: pastırma, Romanian: pastramă, Bulgarian: пастърма)
>   is a meat product usually made from beef, and sometimes from pork,
>   mutton or **turkey**. The raw meat is **brined**, partially dried, seasoned
>   with herbs and spices, then **smoked** and steamed. In the United States,
>   although beef plate is the traditional cut of meat for making
>   pastrami, it is now common to see it made from beef brisket, beef
>   round, and **turkey**. [Emphasis mine]

So yes, the WHO would say turkey and chicken pastrami are carcinogenic.